# Building from the command line to produce a binary for Mac OS 10.5 (and 10.6)

Tags: command-line, build-process, build, macos, compilation

I am referring to the following source: http://clpbar.sourceforge.net

Build process is the standard: `./configure` followed by `make`

If I build on 10.5 I get a binary whose `file` contains: `Mach-O executable i386`
If I build on 10.6 I get a binary whose `file` contains: `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

How can I build from the command line on 10.6 and produce an executable of the type `Mach-O executable i386`, or even better a Universal binary containing executables of both types.

Please test any suggested solutions.

Thanks,
matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Apple dev forums:

```
./configure CC="gcc -arch i386" CXX="g++ -arch i386"
```

Which works perfectly.

Comment: I assume this doesn't build a universal binary with "both" types?

Comment: @rogerdpack try it and see. inspect the binary with the `file` command to see what architectures it includes. Also, see the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the version of GCC distributed with OS X 10.6 builds 64-bit binaries.  The version of GCC distributed with 10.5 builds 32-bit binaries by default.

Before running ./configure, set a few environment variables.  If you want it to be an Intel universal binary with i386 and x86_64 code, set the following variables (assuming you're using bash):

```
export CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export LDFLAGS=$CFLAGS
```

This will tell the configure script to pass these compiler and linker options, and thus build a binary with both the i386 and x86_64 architectures.

Or, if you want it to only build as an i386 binary:

```
export CFLAGS="-arch i386"
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export LDFLAGS=$CFLAGS
```

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work. Could it be that the environment variables are being overridden by ./configure?

Answer (score 1):

Use a -arch flag for each target.  So, e.g.

```
gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 ...
```

would build a fat binary with both.  I believe by default gcc builds to the target architecture, which is x86_64 with OSX 10.6.